# Tabs over menu instead of menu over tabs

Tags: android, menu, tabs, actionbarsherlock

I've got little problem with my program. I'd like to set menu over tabs. I'm using ABS library for tabs as like as for menu.

Here's example how it looks like atm:

[image: #1]

Any ideas? Ask me for code fragments if you need it to solve this problem.